# Save data in CSV file - Py

Tags: python, csv, file, save

i created a dict on python and i want to save key and value of this dict in a CSV file.
also there is a loop which update values' of this dict every time. my code is below , i appreciate if you help me.

```
    for page in pages:
    url = 'http://example.com'
    site = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site.text, 'html.parser')
    r = str(soup).split(";")
    r1 = r[0].split(",")
    r2 = r[1].split(",")
    r3 = r[2].split("@")
    page = {
        "a": int(r3[0]),
        "b": r3[1],
        "c": r3[2],
        "d": r3[3],
        "e" : r3[4],
        "f": r3[5]}
```

Comment: sorry . i want columns to be key of dict and rows to be key values

Answer (score 0):

Use `csv.writer`:

```
import csv
with open('FILENAME.csv', 'w') as f:  
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in page.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: i tried this code but it overwrite data with previous ones. 
for loop , my 'pages' list is included of different stock names and i want new data of each stock name be attached to the end of CSV file and not be overwrote previous data